# Proper data and use of pivot tables

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-8

Maybe better as DBA question...
We have a Laravel/MySQL system. We have 4 model types that are also tables, Categories, Stars, Studios and Videos. Contractors set up pivot tables for each of these model types to house multiple many-to-many relationships to each other. The pivot tables are categoryables, studioables and videoables. These each contain the same structure (categoryables as an example):

`id, category_id, categoryable_type ('App\Models\Video'), categoryable_id (ID of model type), created_at, updated_at`

The current model types we have in each of those pivot tables are:
Categoryables: Star, Studio and Video
Studioables: Star
Videoables: Star, Studio

My questions are:

1. I know Laravel's pivot table naming convention is normally like category_video, so is appending "able" also a proper naming convention?
2. Are these even pivot tables, or are they called something else considering they're set up to have multiple data model types, eliminating a simple relationship of just two tables?
3. What is the best way to house our data for multiple many-to-many relationships? Each model type has a page on our front end, ie. going to a category shows a list of stars, studios and videos. Going to a studio shows a list of categories, stars, and videos, etc. There are 4 possible set ups I can think of:

   3a. videoables table is all we use and it has relationships to
   stars, studios and videos model types.

   3b. We use categoryables, starables and studios only (calling them
   category_video, star_video, studio_video) and each of them only has
   a relationship to the video model type.

   3c. We use all 4 pivot tables and they each contain all of the
   relationships to the other 3 model types. This seems like a lot of
   bloat and redundancy.

   3d. Somewhere in between 3b and 3c. Some sort of perfect combination
   of relationships that enhances query speed and performance without
   suffering from table bloat and redundant data.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and note a question should be for a single focussed answerable question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many relationship needs an extra "mapping" or "junction" table.  ("Pivot" may be used here, but is confusing since it has an unrelated meaning relating to transposing between rows and columns.)

Details on optimal implementation of a [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) table.  (I do not know whether Laravel is efficient here.)

Yes, it sometimes makes sense to have a table with 3 ids instead of just 2.

For further discussion, please provide the `CREATE TABLEs` of one 2- or 3-way relationship table.